# Azure failed Wordpress deployment

Tags: wordpress, azure, deployment

Word press deployment failed. I tried a few times. Below is screenshots of the reasons listed.

[wordpress failed deployment azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxB7q.png)

I have updated with the text logs as @mattias suggested. Screenshot below. Thank you! 
[wordpress failed deployment azure text logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzs8A.png)

Comment: There should be some text logs also, please look for them and see if that makes it clearer.

Comment: solution was 1) setting up a SQL database, 2) setting up server/service plan 3) change the settings of service plan from free to basic.